# Single Table Inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, single-table-inheritance

Is there explicit support for Single Table Inheritance in Django? Last I heard, the feature was still under development and debate.

Are there libraries/hacks I can use in the meantime to capture the basic behavior? I have a hierarchy that mixes different objects. The canonical example of a corporation structure with an Employee class, subclasses for types of employees, and a manager_id (parent_id) would be a good approximation of the problem I am solving.

In my case, I would like to represent the idea that an employee can manage other employees while being managed by a different employee. There are not separate classes for Manager and Worker, which makes this hard to spread across tables. Sub-classes would represent types of employees-programmers, accountants, sales, etc and would be independent of who supervises who (OK, I guess it's no longer a typical corporation in some respect).

Comment: You can use the third party package, which gives you Single Table Inheritance: https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are currently two forms of inheritance in Django - MTI (model table inheritance) and ABC (abstract base classes).

I wrote a [tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20090227074910/http://thisweekindjango.com/articles/2008/jun/17/abstract-base-classes-vs-model-tab/) on what's going on under the hood.

You can also reference the official docs on [model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Comment: Django Typed Models gives you Single-Table-Inheritance: https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models

Answer (score 32):

### Summary

Django's [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) provide the basis for Single Table Inheritance.

However, some effort is required to make it work.

Skip to the end for a re-usable example.

### Background

[Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) describes Single Table Inheritance (STI) as follows:

> Single Table Inheritance maps all fields of all classes of an inheritance structure into a single table.

This is precisely what Django's [proxy model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) does.

Note, that, according to this [blog post from 2010](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/), `proxy` models have been around since Django 1.1.

A "normal" Django model is a *concrete* model, i.e. it has a dedicated table in the database.
There are two types of Django model that do *not* have dedicated database tables, viz. *abstract* models and *proxy* models:

- Abstract models act as *superclasses* for concrete models. An abstract model can define fields, but it does not have a database table. The fields are only added to the database tables for its concrete subclasses.
- Proxy models act as *subclasses* for concrete models. A proxy model cannot define new fields. Instead, it operates on the database table associated with its concrete superclass. In other words, a Django concrete model and its proxies all share a single table.

Django's proxy models provide the basis for Single Table Inheritance, viz. they allow different models to share a single table, and they allow us to define proxy-specific behavior on the Python side. However, Django's default object-relational mapping (ORM) does not provide all the behavior that would be expected, so a little customization is required. How much, that depends on your needs.

Let's build a minimal example, step by step, based on the simple data-model in the figure below:

[image: simple party data model]

### Step 1: basic "proxy model inheritance"

Here's the content of `models.py` for a basic proxy inheritance implementation:

```
from django.db import models


class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    person_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Person(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class Organization(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

`Person` and `Organization` are two types of parties.

Only the `Party` model has a database table, so *all* the fields are defined on this model, including any fields that are specific either to `Person` or to `Organization`.

Because `Party`, `Person`, and `Organization` all use the `Party` database table, we can define a single `ForeignKey` field to `Party`, and assign instances of any of the three models to that field, as implied by the inheritance relation in the figure. Note, that, without inheritance, we would need a separate `ForeignKey` field for each model.

For example, suppose we define an `Address` model as follows:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey(to=Party, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

We can then initialize an `Address` object using e.g. `Address(party=person_instance)` or `Address(party=organization_instance)`.

So far, so good.

However, if we try to get a list of objects corresponding to a proxy model, using e.g. `Person.objects.all()`, we get a list of *all* `Party` objects instead, i.e. both `Person` objects and `Organization` objects. This is because the proxy models still use the model manager from the superclass (i.e. `Party`).

### Step 2: add proxy model managers

To make sure that `Person.objects.all()` only returns `Person` objects, we need to assign a separate [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-model-managers) that filters the `Party` queryset. To enable this filtering, we need a field that indicates which proxy model should be used for the object.

To be clear: creating a `Person` object implies adding a row to the `Party` table. The same goes for `Organization`. To distinguish between the two, we need a column to indicate if a row represents a `Person` or an `Organization`. For convenience and clarity, we add a field (i.e. column) called `proxy_name`, and use that to store the name of the proxy class.

So, enter the `ProxyManager` model manager and the `proxy_name` field:

```
from django.db import models


class ProxyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(proxy_name=self.model.__name__)


class Party(models.Model):
    proxy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    person_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.proxy_name = type(self).__name__
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Person(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ProxyManager()


class Organization(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ProxyManager()
```

Now the queryset returned by `Person.objects.all()` will only contain `Person` objects (and the same for `Organization`).

However, this does not work in the case of a `ForeignKey` relation to `Party`, as in `Address.party` above, because that will always return a `Party` instance, regardless of the value of the `proxy_name` field (also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested)). For example, suppose we create an `address = Address(party=person_instance)`, then `address.party` will return a `Party` instance, instead of a `Person` instance.

### Step 3: extend the `Party` constructor

One way to deal with the related-field issue is to extend the `Party.__new__` method, so it returns an instance of the class specified in the 'proxy_name' field. The end result looks like this:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    PROXY_FIELD_NAME = 'proxy_name'
    
    proxy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    person_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ automatically store the proxy class name in the database """
        self.proxy_name = type(self).__name__
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        party_class = cls
        try:
            # get proxy name, either from kwargs or from args
            proxy_name = kwargs.get(cls.PROXY_FIELD_NAME)
            if proxy_name is None:
                proxy_name_field_index = cls._meta.fields.index(
                    cls._meta.get_field(cls.PROXY_FIELD_NAME))
                proxy_name = args[proxy_name_field_index]
            # get proxy class, by name, from current module
            party_class = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], proxy_name)
        finally:
            return super().__new__(party_class)
```

Now `address.party` will actually return a `Person` instance if the `proxy_name` field is `Person`.

As a last step, we can make the whole thing re-usable:

### Step 4: make it re-usable

To make our rudimentary Single-Table Inheritance implementation re-usable, we can use Django's abstract inheritance:

`inheritance/models.py`:

```
import sys
from django.db import models


class ProxySuper(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    proxy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ automatically store the proxy class name in the database """
        self.proxy_name = type(self).__name__
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """ create an instance corresponding to the proxy_name """
        proxy_class = cls
        try:
            field_name = ProxySuper._meta.get_fields()[0].name
            proxy_name = kwargs.get(field_name)
            if proxy_name is None:
                proxy_name_field_index = cls._meta.fields.index(
                    cls._meta.get_field(field_name))
                proxy_name = args[proxy_name_field_index]
            proxy_class = getattr(sys.modules[cls.__module__], proxy_name)
        finally:
            return super().__new__(proxy_class)


class ProxyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        """ only include objects in queryset matching current proxy class """
        return super().get_queryset().filter(proxy_name=self.model.__name__)
```

Then we can implement our inheritance structure as follows:

`parties/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from inheritance.models import ProxySuper, ProxyManager


class Party(ProxySuper):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    person_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Person(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ProxyManager()


class Organization(Party):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ProxyManager()


class Placement(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey(to=Party, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

More work may be required, depending on your needs, but I believe this covers some of the basics.

Comment: Very great answer, @djvg.
Couldn't `objects = ProxyManager()` be inside `ProxySuper` class?

Comment: @artu-hnrq: Thanks for your kind words. At first glance, putting `ProxyManager` inside `ProxySuper` looks like it could work, and it would certainly look cleaner. However, here's where it breaks down: Suppose, starting from a blank slate, you create a `Person` object and an `Organization` object. In this case, `Party.objects.count()` should yield `2`, but if you put the `objects = ProxyManager()` inside the `ProxySuper` class, `Party.objects.count()` would yield `0`, because it would look for objects with `proxy_name == 'Party'`.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the enlightenment. Think about treat the child models as completely different ones, even with they sharing DB table it doesn't seem that bad to me, but certainly is a down-back to be aware.

Answer (score 21):

I think the OP is asking about Single-Table Inheritance as [defined here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html):

> Relational databases don't support inheritance, so when mapping from objects to databases we have to consider how to represent our nice inheritance structures in relational tables. When mapping to a relational database, we try to minimize the joins that can quickly mount up when processing an inheritance structure in multiple tables. Single Table Inheritance maps all fields of all classes of an inheritance structure into a single table.

That is, a single database table for a whole hierarchy of entity classes. Django does not support that kind of inheritance.

Comment: just use one table, what's not possible in django?

Comment: using one table for multiple models - that's not supported

Comment: @eugene Single-Table Inheritance is one of several ways to get inheritance in a relational database. And I think it is better than the two ways which are supported in django at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

See my attempt:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2408/

> An emulation of "table per hierarchy" a.k.a. "single table inheritance" in Django. The base class must hold all the fields. It's subclasses are not allowed to contain any additional fields and optimally they should be proxies.

Not exactly "single table inheritance", but close enough for many situations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something akin to this.

I have to implement a solution for this problem myself, and here was how I solved it:

```py
class Citrus(models.Model):
    how_acidic = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_value=100)
    skin_color = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()

class TangeloManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TangeloManager, self).get_query_set().filter(type='Tangelo')
    
class Tangelo(models.Model):
   how_acidic = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_value=100)
   skin_color = models.CharField()
   type = models.CharField()
   objects = TangeloManager()

   class Meta:
       # 'appname' below is going to vary with the name of your app
       db_table = u'appname_citrus'
```

This may have some locking issues... I'm not really sure how django handles that off the top of my head. Also, I didn't really test the above code, it's strictly for entertainment purposes, to hopefully put you on the right track.

Comment: interesting idea... but I think syncdb would raise an error such as 'table appname_citrus already exists' as it would try to create the table appname_citrus after it was already created by the Citrus class. I haven't tried though. If this did work, I'd imagine you'd be able to use an abstract base class to avoid having to retype the field names.

Answer (score 2):

this might be of use: https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models
It looks to be somewhat of an implementation of Single Table Inheritance but it has the limitation that subclasses can't have any extra fields.

here is a recent discussion on the django developer mailing list about STI:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/-UOM8HNUnxg/6k34kopzerEJ