# "Create" child model from base model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-socialauth

I have three models, a base called `CommonUser(AbstractUser)` and two children, `Professional(CommonUser)` and `Client(CommonUser)`.

I'm using the [django-rest-social-auth](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) to create users from Facebook, Google, etc., and in my settings, I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CommonUser'`, but I have two steps to create users, first using the social login, after this, I have a form to fill rest of data from a type of user.

I need now to create a Client or a Professional instance from the CommonUser created by the django-rest-social-auth, in other words, I want to "move" the CommonUser instance created by django-rest-social-auth to a Client instance or a Professional instance after submit the second step form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tests and related searchs I found a solution.

In my case, in the view where I'll save the Client or Professional user, I'll use:

```
common_user = CommonUser.objects.get(id=id)
common_user.__class__ = Client
common_user.save()
```

**EDIT**

The method above looks insecure second [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280680/how-dangerous-is-setting-self-class-to-something-else) discussion.

Some more searches and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150372/4472038)

Basically:

```
class CommonUser(AbstractUser):
    # attributes...

    @classmethod
    def create_child(cls, child_class, attrs):
        """
        Inputs:
        - child_class: child class prototype
        - attrs: dictionary of new attributes for child
        """
        try:
            id = attrs.pop('id', None)
            common_user = CommonUser.objects.get(id=id)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        parent_link_field = child_class._meta.parents.get(common_user.__class__, None)
        attrs[parent_link_field.name] = common_user
        for field in common_user._meta.fields:
            value = getattr(common_user, field.name)
            if value:
                attrs[field.name] = value
        s = child_class(**attrs)
        s.save()
        return s


class Professional(CommonUser):
    # attributes...


class Client(CommonUser):
    # attributes...
```

And now I can perform:

```
>>> professional = CommonUser.create_child(Professional, {'id': 1})
>>> client = CommonUser.create_child(Client, {'id': 2})
```