# Use Single table inheritance in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

AFAIK Django supports these types of inheritance:

- [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)
- [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)
- [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

According to the StackOverflow tag description, Single table inheritance is the simplest of several ways to design SQL tables that reflect a class/subclass or generalization/specialization relationship.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/single-table-inheritance/info

Is there a way to use this pattern in Django?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241250/single-table-inheritance-in-django/1720733#1720733

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single Table Inheritance in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241250/single-table-inheritance-in-django)