# In a Django admin, add an inline of a generic relation

Tags: python, django

Here are my simplified models :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import (
    GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation)
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Thing(models.Model):
    '''
    Our 'Thing' class
    with a link (generic relationship) to an abstract config
    '''

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_(u'Name of my thing'))

    # Link to our configs
    config_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        null=True,
        blank=True)
    config_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=True)
    config_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'config_content_type',
        'config_object_id')


class Config(models.Model):
    '''
    Base class for custom Configs
    '''
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_(u'Config Name'))

    thing = GenericRelation(
        Thing,
        related_query_name='config')


class FirstConfig(Config):
    pass


class SecondConfig(Config):
    pass
```

And Here's the admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FirstConfig, SecondConfig, Thing


class FirstConfigInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = FirstConfig


class SecondConfigInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SecondConfig


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Thing

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    '''
    Returns our Thing Config inline
    '''
        if obj is not None:
            m_name = obj.config_object._meta.model_name
            if m_name == "firstconfig":
                return [FirstConfigInline(self.model, self.admin_site), ]
            elif m_name == "secondconfig":
                return [SecondConfigInline(self.model, self.admin_site), ]
        return []


admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
```

So far, I've a `Thing` object with a `FirstConfig` object linked together.
The code is simplified: in an unrelevant part I manage to create my abstract `Config` at a `Thing` creation and set the right `content_type` / `object_id`.

Now I'd like to see this `FirstConfig` instance as an inline (`FirstConfigInline`) in my `ThingAdmin`.

I tried with the `django.contrib.contenttypes.admin.GenericStackedInline`, though it does not work with my current models setup.
I tried to play around with the `fk_name` parameter of my `FirstConfigInline`.
Also, as you can see, I tried to play around with the 'thing' `GenericRelation` attribute on my `Config` Model, without success..

Any idea on how to proceed to correctly setup the admin?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.forms.BaseGenericInlineFormSet) you have to define the ct_fk_field and the ct_field if they were changed from the default values. So it may be enough to set ct_field to config_content_type.

Hope it works!

edit: Those values have to be declared in the Inline:

```
class SecondConfigInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SecondConfig
    ct_fk_field = "config_object_id"
    ct_field = "config_content_type"
```

edit2:

I just realized an error in my assumption. Usually you should declare the Foreignkey on the Inline-model. Depending on the rest of your code you could just remove the generic Foreignkey on Thing+the genericRelation on Config and declare a normal Foreignkey on the Config-Basemodel.

Comment: I've already tried to add the `fk_name` (to `FirstConfig.thing.config_content_type.through`), but `AttributeError: 'ReverseGenericManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'`.    
  Also tried to to define a `ct_field`/`ct_fk_field`, but I think this would apply if i'd do a ConfigAdmin, to get my Things Inlines!

Comment: Did you try adding them to the Inline?

Comment: Yes, I also tried as you suggested and I get the `ValueError: 'myapp.Config' has no ForeignKey to 'myapp.Thing'.` because the "FK" is on a CT on the Thing and not in my Config. I tried different combination, I feel the answer lies in the 'Reverse GenericRelation' with it's 'related_query_name' but no luck so far for the inline.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I'll give it a try anyway.

I think the solution depends on what kind of relation you intend to create between `Thing` and your `Config` subclasses.

### many-to-one/one-to-many

The way it is currently set up, it looks like a many-to-one relation: each `Thing` points to a single `Config` subclass, and many `Thing`s can point to the same `Config` subclass. Due to the generic relation, each `Thing` can point to a different model (not necessarily a `Config` subclass, unless you do some extra work).

In this case I guess it would make more sense to put the inline on the admin for the `Config`. That is, create a `GenericStackedInline` for `Thing` (which has the `GenericForeignkey`), and add the inline to a `ConfigAdmin`, which you can then use for all `Config` subclasses. Also see the example below. The generic inline will then automatically set the correct `content_type` and `object_id`.

### many-to-many

On the other hand, if you are looking for a many-to-many relation between `Thing` and each `Config` subclass, then I would move the `GenericForeignkey` into a separate many-to-many table (lets call it `ThingConfigRelation`).

A bit of code says more than a thousand words, so let's split up your `Thing` class as follows:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ThingConfigRelation(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(to=Thing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    config_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='content_type',
                                      fk_field='object_id')
```

Now it does make sense to add an inline to the `ThingAdmin`. The following is a bare-bones example of an admin that works for both sides of the relation:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.admin import GenericStackedInline
from .models import Thing, FirstConfig, SecondConfig, ThingConfigRelation


class ConventionalTCRInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ThingConfigRelation
    extra = 0


class GenericTCRInline(GenericStackedInline):
    model = ThingConfigRelation
    extra = 0


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ConventionalTCRInline]


class ConfigAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GenericTCRInline]


admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
admin.site.register(FirstConfig, ConfigAdmin)
admin.site.register(SecondConfig, ConfigAdmin)
```

Note that we use the conventional inline for the `ForeignKey`-side of the relation (i.e. in `ThingAdmin`), and we use the generic inline for the `GenericForeignKey`-side (in `ConfigAdmin`).

A tricky bit would be filtering the `content_type` and `object_id` fields on the `ThingAdmin`.

### ... something completely different:

Another option might be to get rid of the `GenericForeignKey` altogether and use some kind of single-table inheritance implementation with plain old `ForeignKeys` instead, a bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894618).