# Create Django abstract child model refering to the table of the parent model

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, single-table-inheritance

I have a model (`Parent`) that has a table in the database (table `app1_parent`) in a first app (`app1`).

In another app (`app2`), I would like to add functionnality to this `Parent` model, but still refer to the existing `Parent` table (table `app1_parent`), which is part of the other app (`app1`).

If I create in `app2` the `Child` model that simply inherite from `Parent`, I end up with two different tables: `app1_parent` and `app2_child`

I'd like to know if I can create an (abstract ?) child model (`Child`) that refers to the table of the `Parent` model, without adding additional field, but adding new methods and properties.
(Basically I would want to do the contrary of what abstract tables have been built to do)

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Child(Parent):
    
    def my_method(self):
        return 'done'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Is there another way to achieve my result?

PS: of course, the objective would be not to modify the `app1.Parent` model and `app1.parent` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found a solution my own answer: using Django proxy models to achieve single-table inheritance:

```
class Child(Parent):
    
    def my_method(self):
        return 'done'

    class Meta:
        proxy= True
```

very good answer on how to expand single-table inheritance to have child models identified as "distinct" of the Parent model, and between them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894618/12505071